# Matrices in C implementation

Tags: c, matrix

I recently wrote a C implementation of Matrices with add, subtract, and multiply. I want to expand this out eventually where I can diagonalize, efficiently square, row-reduce, etc...

I was wondering if there are any more efficient ways to do what I'm currently doing (I'm really new to C and pointers/references in general) and without changing too much, getting

```
*(result.matrix+ i*r  + j)
```

to work like

```
result[i][j]
```

Here's the code below

```
/**
    Matrix Multiplication
    matrices.c
    Matrix data structure in C.

    @author Michael Asper
    @version 1.0 3/29/17
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct Matrix {
    int     rowSize;
    int     columnSize;
    long int*    matrix;
} Matrix;


/**
    Randomizes the elements of a matrix

    @param *m pointer to Matrix to randomize;
*/
void randomize(Matrix *m){
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < m->rowSize ; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < m->columnSize; j++){
            *(m->matrix + i*m->rowSize  + j)= rand() % 5000;
        }
    }
}

/**
    Returns a r x c Matrix with all 0s.

    @param r The row size of the matrix
    @param c The column size of the matrix
    @return r x c Matrix
*/
Matrix createMatrix(int r, int c){
    Matrix temp = {r, c, calloc(r * c, sizeof(long int *))};
    return temp;
}

/**
    Returns a r x c Matrix with random numbers.

    @param r The row size of the matrix
    @param c The column size of the matrix
    @return r x c Matrix
*/
Matrix createRandMatrix(int r, int c){
    Matrix temp = createMatrix(r,c);
    randomize(&temp);
    return temp;
}

/**
    Prints matrix.

    @param *m Pointer to Matrix you want to print
*/
void printMatrix(Matrix *m){

    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < m->rowSize ; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < m->columnSize; j++){
            printf("%li ", *(m->matrix + i*m->rowSize  + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

/**
    Adds two matrices together

    @param *a pointer to first matrix (A);
    @param *b pointer to second matrix (B);
    @return A+B
*/
Matrix add(Matrix *a, Matrix *b){
    //check if matrices are compatible
    if(a->rowSize != b->rowSize || a->columnSize != b->columnSize){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Incompatible sizes");
        exit(0);
    }
    //create result matrix
    int r = a->rowSize;
    int c = a->columnSize;
    Matrix result = createMatrix(r,c);
    //add matrices
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < r ; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < c; j++){
            //result[i][j] = a[i][j]+b[i][j]
            *(result.matrix+ i*r  + j) = *(a->matrix + i*r  + j) + *(b->matrix + i*r  + j);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

/**
    Subtracts two matrices together

    @param *a pointer to first matrix (A);
    @param *b pointer to second matrix (B);
    @return A-B
*/
Matrix sub(Matrix *a, Matrix *b){
    //check if matrices are compatible
    if(a->rowSize != b->rowSize || a->columnSize != b->columnSize){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Incompatible sizes");
        exit(0);
    }
    //create result matrix
    int r = a->rowSize;
    int c = a->columnSize;
    Matrix result = createMatrix(r,c);
    //subtracts matrix
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < r ; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < c; j++){
            //result[i][j] = a[i][j]-b[i][j]
            *(result.matrix+ i*r  + j) = *(a->matrix + i*r  + j) - *(b->matrix + i*r  + j);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

/**
    Multiplies two matrices together

    @param *a pointer to first matrix (A);
    @param *b pointer to second matrix (B);
    @return A*B
*/
Matrix multiply(Matrix *a, Matrix *b){
    //check if matrices are compatible
    if(a->columnSize != b->rowSize ){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Incompatible sizes");
        exit(0);
    }

    //initialize return matrix
    int r = a->rowSize;
    int c = b->columnSize;
    Matrix result = createMatrix(r,c);

    //multiply matrices
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < r ; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < c; j++){
            long int sum = 0;
            int k;
            for(k = 0; k < a->columnSize; k++){
                //sum += a[i][k] * b[k][j]
                sum = sum + (*(a->matrix + i*a->rowSize  + k)**(b->matrix + k*b->rowSize  + j));
            }
            *(result.matrix+ i*r  + j) = sum;
        }
    }
    return result;
}


int main(){
    // seed random with time
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    //setup random matrices and multiply
    Matrix a = createRandMatrix(3,100);
    Matrix b = createRandMatrix(100,3);
    Matrix result = multiply(&a,&b);
    printMatrix(&result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `3/29/17` **don't**. Use the international standard which everyone understands: `2017-03-29`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just wanted to comment on your question about accessing the array efficiently. You ask:

> I was wondering if there are any more efficient ways to do what I'm currently doing (I'm really new to C and pointers/references in general) and without changing too much, getting
>
> `*(result.matrix+ i*r  + j)`
>
> to work like
>
> `result[i][j]`

One way is to do as @mdfst13 has recommended and allocate an array of arrays. That's a fine way to do it, but it can be a performance issue when accessing the array element by element in a loop. CPUs generally optimize to access the next few bytes past the last access since you're likely to need bytes near the ones you previously accessed. If you have a separate array per row, this can throw off that optimization when you reach the end of each row. You'd want to first profile to verify that's an issue or not. If it is, another option you have is to leave it as a single allocation and simply write an accessor function. Something like:

```
long int getElement(const Matrix m, const int r, const int c)
{
    return *(m.matrix + r * m.rowSize + c);
}
```

This also allows you the opportunity to do some range checking when in debug mode by doing something like:

```
long int getElement(const Matrix m, const int r, const int c)
{
#if DEBUG
    assert((r >= 0) && (r < m.rowSize));
    assert((c >= 0) && (c < m.colSize));
#endif
    return *(m.matrix + r * m.rowSize + c);
}
```

(Or if you want to pass a pointer in instead of passing by value, as suggested in mdfst13's answer, you could change the prototype to take a pointer to a `Matrix` and dereference the fields via pointer.)

Now when you want to access an element of the array, you would write:

```
long int x = getElement(result, i, j);
```

It's not as concise as just `result[i][j]`, but it's better than writing out the math every time and potentially getting it wrong in some subtle way.

Comment: I'll eventually being using OpenMP/MPI to parallelize this code for my university's cluster, would either accessing method affect parallelization?

Comment: It would depend entirely on the access patterns. Will different threads be reading and writing data to/from the same matrix at the same time? (Sounds like a bad idea, but I don't know your requirements.) Do you tend to work on columns or more on rows? The best thing to do is put it in a function that you can change later. That way you can come up with a (deterministic - not random!) test and run it under both conditions to see which is faster.

Comment: There's no pass by reference in C. I know this may be nit picking, but IMO one should use correct terminology throughout to avoid confusion. (+1 for the rest of the answer though)

Comment: @DanielJour Fair point! I guess I should have said pass a pointer to the data in. I'll update it.

Comment: Would "throw off that optimization" slow down the performance?

Comment: Does "have a separate array per row" mean the nested loop?

Comment: Yes, it would slow down performance because you would get a lot of cache misses. By "separate array per row" I mean allocating an array of arrays rather than 1 single array. In this scenario you have an array where each element is a pointer to 1 row. Then each row is itself a different array. They may or may not be near each other in memory, which means they likely won't benefit from the caching the CPU does automatically.

Answer (score 5):

You can read about the general handling of multi-dimension dynamic sized arrays at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/917783/6660678).  But specific to your code

> ```
>     long int*    matrix;
> ```

Replace this with

```
    long int **  matrix;
```

And then change

> ```
> Matrix createMatrix(int r, int c){
>     Matrix temp = {r, c, calloc(r * c, sizeof(long int *))};
>     return temp;
> }
> ```

to something like

```
Matrix createMatrix(int r, int c){
    Matrix temp = {r, c, calloc(r, sizeof(long int *))};

    if (temp.matrix == NULL) {
        /* panic */
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        temp.matrix[i] = calloc(c, sizeof temp.matrix[i][0]);

        if (temp.matrix[i] == NULL) {
            /* panic */
        }
    }

    return temp;
}
```

You should check the result of `calloc` before using.  Replace `/* panic */` with any number of alternatives.  E.g. `exit`, log an error, print an error message, or all or some of these.  The failure is rare, but it helps to respond to it early.

Your original code used the wrong type in the `sizeof` command.  Presumably this didn't matter because the pointer type was at least as big as a `long int`.

To avoid that kind of bug, consider doing it the way that I did in the second `calloc`.  Give it an example variable of the right type and let it figure out the type.  That way if you update the type in the future, you don't have to update every `calloc` to match.  When using `sizeof` this way, you don't need the parentheses.

Then you can change lines like

> ```
>             *(m->matrix + i*m->rowSize  + j)= rand() % 5000;
> ```

to a more readable

```
            m->matrix[i][j] = rand() % 5000;
```

This also gives you the ability to have different sized rows, but you don't seem to need that.

It looks odd to me to pass `struct` objects by value.  I would normally expect functions to return pointers to `struct` objects.  Or pass a pointer to the `struct` into the function, which populates it.

Most of the time people just write `long` and not `long int`.  There's no harm to writing it out; that's just not what I normally see.

And you should `free` the memory that you `calloc` when you're done with it.  Note that you have to do this row by row, just as you created it.  Then the overall variable.

Comment: Why do you think that this would be better? (Apart from fixing the bug, of course.)

Comment: I would suggest allocating the array as `calloc(rows, sizeof(long[cols]));`, so you have a contiguous block of memory. Then when you need to access it (in a readable way) just write `long (*matrix)[m->c] = m->matrix;`, so you can access it like `matrix[i][j];  /* i < m->rowSize && j < m->colSize */`.

Answer (score 2):

A few notes:

1. Implement multiplication of a matrix by a scalar (i.e., a real number). Then your subtraction routine becomes:

   1. Multiply matrix `B` by scalar `-1`. Let this resultant matrix be `C`
   2. Add `A` and `C`

   More useful and less duplicated code. (Why did you not think of implementing scalar multiplication in the first place? Closure under addition and scalar multiplication (and the presence of a null element) define vector spaces in general, and vector spaces of matrices (real or complex) in particular.)
2. Some might disagree with me, but I think all indexed accesses and size declarations should use parameters of type `size_t`, as that is the type deemed fit for this purpose by the standard. This means that all those `r`s and `c`s should be of type `size_t`, instead of `int`. Also, so should `rowSize` and `columnSize`. I would prefer calling them either `rows` and `columns` or `numRows` and `numColumns` respectively, as there is less ambiguity about their purpose that way.
3. Matrices are defined on either real or complex, not integer, scalar fields. I guess that the type of an element of a matrix should be `double`, if not, at least `float`. This will come in useful when calculating matrix inverses, as they involve division, and the field of integers is not closed under division.
4. Everything that can be `const` should be `const`. That includes all function parameters, as you do not modify them or their contents.

Comment: 1) is definitely a good idea, and 2) you're completely corrupt about rowSize and columnSize being ambiguous as I got really confused writing this partial pivot row reduce function (confused rowLength as rowSize when rowSize is numRows). 3) Just converted to double as well :)

Comment: @kllrshrk I guess you meant "correct", not "corrupt" ;)

Comment: As an aside, I've recently been trying out functional programming, so I've been working on a FP-compatible matrix implementation in Scala. If you've got any interest that way, you might want to take a look at https://github.com/tamchow/ScalaStuff/blob/master/src/in/tamchow/LinearAlgebra/LinearAlgebra.scala

Answer (score 0):

If your code runs on a x86/ x64 platform, you could also check if sse is available (which is true on all modern cpu's, but can be verified by cpuid) and use sse to further boost your program's performance. See http://download.intel.com/design/PentiumIII/sml/24504501.pdf

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/74433)

Comment: Right, that's reasonable, I will remember this next time.

Comment: It's not too late for this answer, yet ;-)

Answer (score 0):

#### Macro suggestion

I wanted to quickly suggest something I haven't seen in the other answers.  You could use a macro to make your code look nicer:

```
#define M(m, i, j)    *((m)->matrix + (i)*((m)->rowSize) + (j))
```

So code like this:

> ```
> *(result.matrix+ i*r  + j) = *(a->matrix + i*r  + j) + *(b->matrix + i*r  + j);
> ```

becomes:

```
M(&result, i, j) = M(a, i, j) + M(b, i, j);
```

The advantage of this macro over something like a `getElement()` function is that you can use `M()` as an lvalue, whereas `getElement()` can only be an rvalue.